# iOS Google Play Games SDK - How to invite friends to social circles?

Tags: ios, google-play-games

Apple's Game Center has really gone down the toilet recently so I'm adding support for Google Play Games leaderboards and achievements to my iOS games. I'm displaying the leaderboards myself by downloading the scores using the GPGLeaderboard class. There's a property called "social" that lets me download the scores of friends - *"A social leaderboard is a public leaderboard filtered by people within the local player's circles."* Is there an API that will let me invite other players to my game so I can see them in these social leaderboards? I'm not sure how people are supposed to set up these social circles?

Answer (score 0):

Check this documentation: [Starting a real-time multiplayer game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/ios/realtimeMultiplayer#starting_a_real-time_multiplayer_game).

> - **Invite players button.** Lets the user invite friends to join a game session or specify some number of random opponents for auto-matching. When the player selects this option, your app should display either the built-in player selection user interface (UI) provided by the SDK or a custom UI for player selection.

You might also want to check on this [GPGLeaderboard Class Reference](https://developers.google.com/games/services/ios/api/interface_g_p_g_leaderboard) wherein `leaderboard` objects must be created with a `leaderboard ID`. Once a `leaderboard` object is created, you may interact with it using the provided set of [actions](https://developers.google.com/games/services/ios/api/interface_g_p_g_leaderboard#public-member-functions).

Comment: I don't want to invite people to join a multiplayer game though. I just want to be able to see the scores of my friends who play the same game in the Social Leaderboards. Google docs say ....   "If friends in your Google+ circles share their activity for the same game you're playing with your Google+ account, you can compare scores on the game's social leaderboard." but how do they share their activity? Google has moved from requiring a Google+ account to using an anonymous Gamer ID so how do I see their scores in my social leaderboards?    https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6061473